# Saving a modified InfoPath form to its form library

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath

Within our corporate SharePoint 2007 site, there is a particular form library that contains 10 separate files.  9 of these are either Excel, Word, or PowerPoint files and one of these is an InfoPath 2007 form that serves as a report.  After noticing an error within this InfoPath form, I saved this InfoPath form to my local directory and then, within the design mode of InfoPath, I modified this InfoPath form.

What is the proper way to save this modified InfoPath form to its form library?  Everything that I have tried results in nobody except myself having access to this modified InfoPath form.  I can open this InfoPath form without error but when my coworkers try to open this InfoPath form on their machines, they receive this error: “The form cannot be opened because it requires the domain permission level and it currently has restricted permission.  To fix this problem, open the form from the location it was published to."

Answer (score 0):

If you have the form open in Infopath, go to the Design checker and click on Change Compatibility Settings. Look in the Security and Trust section on the left, and make sure it is set to to Automatically Detect Security Level.

I had this same issue, and it was manually set to another option. While you're in there, what options are checked off under the Compatibility section?

Comment: No options are checked off under the Compatibility section.

Comment: I modified the setting of this InfoPath form so that, within the  Security and Trust section, the "Automatically Detect Security Level" option was checked.  I uploaded this InfoPath form back to its form library.  I am able to open this form without any issues but when my coworkers try to open this InfoPath form on their machines, they receive the same error that I mentioned above.  

Please help!